# Can I control each row value of dynamic html table code added in JavaScript from the cs file?

Tags: asp.net

```
<tbody id="hiddenRows">
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td><input id="ck" runat="server" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlProductName" AutoPostBack="True"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProductName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="ddlSupliersName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td><input id="unitPrice" type="text" name="unitPirce" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><input id="discount" type="text" name="discount" runat="server" /></td>
        <td><span id="subtotal"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(OrderBiz biz = new OrderBiz())
    {
        DataSet ds = biz.SetOrderItem(ddlCompanName.SelectedValue, ddlContactName.SelectedValue
            , ddlProductName.SelectedValue, ddlSupliersName.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(unitPrice.Value)
            , Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Value), Convert.ToInt32(discount.Value) / 100 );
    }
}
```

This is part of my code.
If i create dynamically and get an additional input id value, I don't know how to send data to db using that id value.

What I want is to save each id value in the property and send it to db in one method.